# Structure of composition of permutations

Tags: cryptanalysis, finite-field, group-theory, permutation

If $P_1, P_2$ are finite permutations, what can we say about $P_3 = P_1 \cdot P_2$?  That is, what properties of the *composition* of permutations can be inferred from the properties of the *permutations which are composed*?

Since permutations form a group, for any $P_2$ and $P_3$, there exists a $P_1$ that when composed with $P_2$ gives $P_3$.  So there range of composition spans the entire space of permutations.  That doesn't mean, however, that we can't learn certain things about their structure or nature.  For example: **If we know the cyclic structure of $P_1$ and $P_2$, can we learn the cyclic structure of $P_3$?**

Or, **if $P_1$ is a simple cycle (that is, a shift with no fixed points), and $P_2$ is known, what is the range of $P_1 \cdot P_2$?**

Or, **what is the relationship between $P_1 \cdot P_2$ and $P_2 \cdot P_1$?**

More generally: What, if any, properties of composition of permutations can be inferred from the properties of the individual permutations?  Or, if you argue that no such properties can be inferred, please prove it.

Comment: "if $P_1$ is a simple cycle (that is, a shift with no fixed points), what is the range of $P_1 \cdot P_2$?" - I believe you answered that in your previous paragraph "So their range of composition spans the entire space of permutations"

Comment: @poncho Clarified wording to indicate "what is the range of composition for a **known P2**"

Answer (score 1):

**If we know the cyclic structure of** $P_1$ **and** $_2$, **can we learn the cyclic structure of** $_3$?

No. Consider the case when $P_1$ is all fixed points bar a 2-cycle and $P_2$ has the same structure. $P_3$ could be the identity; it could consist of two disjoint 2-cycles and the rest fixed points; it could be a 3-cycle and the rest fixed points. We can say that if $P_1$ and $P_2$ belong to the same subgroup (e.g. membership of the alternating group can be inferred from the cycle structure) then so does $P_3$.

**If** $P_1$ **is a simple cycle (that is, a shift with no fixed points), and** $_2$ **is known, what is the range of** $_1⋅_2$?

It's the union of right cosets of shift subgroups whose intersection is $P_2$. This is close to tautologous, but I can't think of a better way to describe it.

**what is the relationship between $_1⋅_2$ and $_2⋅_1$**?

It's a conjugate by $P_2$ (and so in particular has the same cycle structure). Let $Q=P_1P_2$ so that $P_1=QP_2^{-1}$ and $P_2\cdot P_1=P_2QP_2^{-1}$. $Q$ has $n!$ such representations there is a representation corresponding to any given conjugate and so no further structure can be inferred.